# For filename in os.listdir(directory) is raising exception "name 'filenames' not defined" after modification

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-imaging-library

So, I have started programming Python (3) recently. This was for a project about "averaging images"; take the pixel values of images, find the average, and put it into an image. I started using Python as I had heard about the Python Imaging Library (it works well for my use) and programming it in JavaScript would be too tedious.

So, my code:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from PIL import Image
import os

main_dir = "/Users/dragonsruleethanslota/Downloads/image_averaging_python3.6"
image_dir = f"{main_dir}/images"
image_list = []
invisibles = [".DS_Store", ".Trashes"]

def reset_temptxt():
    with open(f"{main_dir}/temp.txt", "w") as temptxt:
        temptxt.write("")

def check_extensions(countq = False):
    count = 0
    for filename in os.listdir(image_dir): # Problematic lines of code
        if filename in invisibles:         # Also problematic
            continue                       # Also problematic
        try:
            Image.open(f"{image_dir}/{filename}")
        except OSError:
            count = count + 1
    if countq:
        return count # Returns amount of bad file extensions
    else:
        return not count # Returns boolean of whether there are bad file extensions or not

if check_extensions():
    for file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if filename in invisibles:
            continue
        image = Image.open(f"{image_dir}/{file}")
        image_list.append([image, image.load()])

reset_temptxt()

def do_averages(xpixel, ypixel):
    with open(f"{main_dir}/temp.txt", "a") as temptxt:
       for (img, pixel_img) in image_list:
           pixel = pixel_img[xpixel, ypixel]
           temptxt.write("{},{},{}".format(*pixel))

do_averages(0, 0)
```

(I also have a file called `temp.txt` and a folder called `images`)

What's extremely confusing about all of this was when I came back overnight to start it back up: I went and finished programming the `do_averages()` function then ran it in anticipation of seeing something in `temp.txt`, however nothing ran. This was because the `check_extensions()` function failed as macOS adds a file called ".DS_Store" to folders. This caused the function to fail; I added the `invisibles` list and a check if the current file was in any of these files. If so, then skip over the rest of the code.

However, this new line causes an error to be raised! Apparently Python can't find the variable `filename` (the one being assigned to by the loop). And what's even *more* confusing is how when I remove the check, no error is raised. Please help; I'm new to Python and feel like this is an oblivious mistake!

Comment: `if filename in invisibles:` should be `if file in invisibles:` because filename is not a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't located where you think...
Look on your seconde function check_extensions:

```py
if check_extensions():
    for file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if filename in invisibles:
            continue
        image = Image.open(f"{image_dir}/{file}")
        image_list.append([image, image.load()])
```

HERE : it can't find filename... Because you said "for file in", and then asked for filename !!!
So decide, use either:

```py
if check_extensions():
    for filename in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if filename in invisibles:
            continue
        image = Image.open(f"{image_dir}/{file}")
        image_list.append([image, image.load()])
```

Or:

```py
if check_extensions():
    for file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if file in invisibles:
            continue
        image = Image.open(f"{image_dir}/{file}")
        image_list.append([image, image.load()])
```

Comment: As I thought, just an oblivious mistake. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, errors like this always happen like when you forget a global or something... XD

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
if check_extensions():
    for file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if filename in invisibles:
            continue
```

You are trying to access `filename` but the variable you are using in your loop is `file`.
Change it to:

```
if check_extensions():
    for file in os.listdir(image_dir):
        if file in invisibles:
            continue
```